# Rails app not working with Apache + Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I am trying to host a rails2 application on a new Virtual Machine which is CentOS 6 with Parallels Plesk Panel 11 (64-bit). 
I have installed RVM,ruby,rails, and passanger Succefully using the steps given [here](http://rabblemedia.net/blog/installing-rvm-ruby-rails-and-passenger-centos-6.html/)

I have followed all the steps correctly. 
I have installed **ruby 1.8.7** and **rails 2.0.2**

Now the thing is that, I am able to run the application using the Webrick server at 3000 port on the new server. Everything works fine there. But when I want to run it with apache, it doesn't run. when I hit the url it returns the page

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /account/login was not found on this server. Apache
>   Server at www.mem.com Port 80

Here is my passanger.conf file :

> /etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf

```
    LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/passenger-3.0.19/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/passenger-3.0.19
   PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.8.7-p371/ruby
```

Here is my virtual Host code :

> /etc/httpd/sites-available/mem.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin youremail@example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/mem/public
 ServerName www.mem.com
 ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mem/error.log
 CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mem/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. There already a Virtual Host had been created with different Document Root by the web hosting company. I moved my app directory to that path and application started. Thanks everyone for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You may also see this if you manage to set `DocumentRoot` to the wrong or non-existing directory.  If you can't figure this out, double check that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a this directory block inside your VirtualHost

```
<Directory /var/www/mem/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Paul. I added the directory block, But still it is not working.

Comment: Not entirely familiar with your OS… Are you sure the virtual host is enabled? i.e. does your main Apache config include everything in your /etc/httpd/sites-available directory? Or do you need to create a symlink to it from /etc/httpd/sites-enabled - on Ubuntu there is a utility called a2ensite to create the link for you.

Comment: In my apache conf file I have simply added frollowing statement 
"Include sites-enabled/*.conf" at bottom and no any other change. Also created a link by following command :

"sudo ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/mem.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/mem.conf"

Comment: Sounds good, and you're sure the module is being loaded? I guess you are loading in everything in /etc/httpd/conf.d/

Comment: Sorry but how to verify the module is being loaded or not?

Comment: try `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` outputted list should include 'passenger_module'

Comment: Yes! It has "passenger_module (shared)" entry in the resulted list.

Comment: And you have NameVirtualHost *:80 in you Apache config before the Include sites-enabled line?

Comment: Yes. you are right. the site-enabled line is at the bottom of page!

Comment: Here is a code from httpd.conf : 

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
#NameVirtualHost *:80
#

(Removed the commented Code in between.)
#
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
#    DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
#    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
#    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
#    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
#</VirtualHost>
GracefulShutDownTimeout 3
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
Include sites-enabled/*.conf

Comment: Out of ideas for now, sorry, will have a think and try and check back later, try taking a look at Apache logs, good luck.

Comment: Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: Pleas anybody have any suggestions? I am still stuck with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running a CentOS 6 box with Apache & the Passenger module. My site configuration lives within the `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/` folder. Here's my conf:

```
# /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/hello-world.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hello-world.localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hello/public
    <Directory /var/www/hello/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Always remember to restart apache:

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

Hopefully this might help you. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Moz, I did it but still not working I am getting following error  at /var/log/httpd/error_log

[Thu Feb 07 05:20:22 2013] [error] [client 157.55.35.37] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/account

I am not getting why apache looking file in /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/  instead of document root path /var/www/mem

DO you have any Idea? LEt me know if you want any other details

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your Name Based Virtual Host is not working, this should output your virtual host setup, `apache2 -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` - does that help?

Comment: Now I am able to launch the application with apache. But the problem is that, It is not running on the default 80 port. It is running on every valid port other than 80. I tried by setting the port to 80 in "/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/mem.conf" But it is still giving me the same error as above. Now my application is running on port 3000. for that I have to write this port number after the domain name. SO my URL becomes www.domainname:3000.com. I want to run it on port 80. What would be the reson? Why it is not running on the port 80?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem myself, though with a rails3 app on rhel 6.2 (64bit) and ruby-1.8.7 with https. I fixed my problem by adding following line at the end (after "VirtualHost" section) in /etc/httpd/conf.d/myapp.conf:

```
    PassengerPreStart https://<url-to-my-rails-app>
```

Once apache is restarted, my app shows up properly.

You can find more information from passenger user guide for apache: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#User_switching

Answer (score -5):

Disable selinux.

Answer must be at least 30 characters.

Comment: If you could expand on how to do that, it would make this answer more useful — *and* beat the 30-character limit! =)

Comment: i agree.. why do we need to disable selinux?